# switching between two activity in Android

Tags: android

My requirement is I will start Video player activity after some delay Video player activity should hide and  GPS activity should show after some delay  GPS activity should hide and video player activity should show and this should continue. 
How can I achieve this requirement, please suggest me.
Thank you in advance

Thanks and Regards,
Devindrappa

Answer (score 1):

When your activity starts put Handler like this in your `oncreate` method:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class));
   }
}, specify your time here);
```

The above handler will start your activity after the time period which you will specify.Do the same in your both activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that tutorial could help you:

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/

Ivan